# Calculate fields referring to other layer?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, intersection

I have to analyze different pathway segments based on a few variables:

- Number of properties crossed (polygons)
- Length of paths on public land (polygons)
- Number of intersection with stream (lines)
- Number of intersection with river (polygons)

Is there a way to calculate these information directly in the attribute table using the field calculator?